# DevPay and Mfa are mutually exclusive authorization methods

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to add MFA-deletion to my S3 bucket with the AWS-cli with the following command:

```
aws s3api put-bucket-versioning --bucket <my-bucket-name> --versioning-configuration '{"MFADelete":"Enabled","Status":"Enabled"}' --mfa 'arn:aws:iam::<code-found-at-iam-page>:mfa/root-account-mfa-device <my-google-authenticator-code>'
```

but the response I get is this:

> An error occurred (InvalidRequest) when calling the
>   PutBucketVersioning operation: DevPay and Mfa are mutually exclusive
>   authorization methods.

which makes no sense as I have never used DevPay. My security group for the instance has S3FullAccess enabled so that shouldn't be a problem either.

Any suggestions on what the problem might be would be appreciated.

Answer (score 19):

*I submitted a case to AWS and they answer with this:*

> That error response typically gets returned when the API cannot
>   perform the MFA Delete task due to the request being made with
>   non-root credentials. The only way to turn on MFA Delete is to use the
>   credentials from the root user of the account

**Simple solution!**

Comment: arigato, saved us some time

Answer (score 4):

I just got the same error when attempting to perform this using the AWS CloudShell, although I was using the root user (and confirmed I was root using the CloudShell). The same command worked when run from the local CLI.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This is exactly the same problem I ran into!

Comment: CloudShell works if you run "aws configure" and configure with root credentials

Answer (score 0):

To enable/disable MFA delete on s3 bucket you must configure your aws command line with root access key .

Check the Prerequisites part

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-undelete-configuration/