# AWS S3 bucket MFA enable

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

First, below is my configuration details from EC2 instance.

CLI Command:

```
aws s3api put-bucket-versioning --bucket ewiglife-mfa-testin --versioning-configuration Status=Enabled,MFADelete=Enabled --mfa "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:mfa/root-account-mfa-device xxxxxx"
```

I am getting this error message:

> An error occurred (InvalidRequest) when calling the PutBucketVersioning operation: DevPay and Mfa are mutually exclusive authorization methods.

Comment: This is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45602558/devpay-and-mfa-are-mutually-exclusive-authorization-methods

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DevPay and Mfa are mutually exclusive authorization methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45602558/devpay-and-mfa-are-mutually-exclusive-authorization-methods)

Answer (score 0):

Try running that command using Root User of the AWS account.